# Is `pull` needed after checking out a new branch?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-checkout

In case of a git-project with several branches, the question is when you checkout a new branch (first time), is a `git pull` needed ?

```
$master> git checkout branchA
$branchA> git pull
```

Note that the idea here is that both commands are executed right after each other (this question is not about when-or-why you should run `git pull`)

I've tested this, but so far the `pull` doesn't pull in new commits, but some people claim that the `pull` is needed. Can someone describe a scenario in which this is indeed needed or maybe break this myth?

Comment: "some people claim that..." when some people claim that some people claim something you should refer to that otherwise we have no way of knowing what they mean

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If I say that some people claim that a pull is needed .... what else do you need, names ?

Comment: A link would be nice

Comment: Well, I just asked, and it is something they've experienced

Comment: Asked where? And who?

Comment: One of the guys who did the claim he is sitting right next to me :)

Comment: Why don't you ask the magical guy making the claim to answer your question?

Comment: As I said, it is something he experienced, so this person cannot prove anything. Thats why I'm asking this question: Is it needed to do a `pull` after checking out a new branch (if it helps, forget about the `claim`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the branch is already on origin and you do not have a local copy and you check it out, then it will contain all commits anyway so you do not need the pull after.
If you already have a local copy of the branch it will checkout that one, and in that case you use `git fetch origin` to see if there have been any changes and the `git pull` to get those changes. if your branch is not set up to track the remote branch then you will need to add the branch name at the end of the pull, eg `git pull origin branchA`